# Display dynamic title in mapview android

Tags: android

I am displaying multiple points in mapview by using for loop dynamically from the values of api and I am getting the pinpoints but I am unable to display multiple title which I am getting from the api I used to get the title but I am showing the last one again and again on each and every pinpoint. Here is my code. Please help.

```
for(int i = 0;i<adapt_objgps.latitude_array.length;i++){
    System.out.println("valud oer values:::" +adapt_objgps.latitude_array[1]);
    lat = adapt_objgps.latitude_array[i];
    longit = adapt_objgps.longitude_array[i];
    title = adapt_objgps.title_array[i];
    address = adapt_objgps.address_array[i];

    total = lat+","+longit;
    System.out.println("value of total:::" +total);
    System.out.println("value of title:::"+title);

    mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapview.getOverlays();

    Drawable drawable = myrefgps.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);

    double dLat = Double.parseDouble(lat) *1E6;
    double dLongotitue =Double.parseDouble(longit) *  1E6;

    int iLat = (int) dLat;
    int iLongtitue = (int) dLongotitue;

    point = new GeoPoint(iLat, -iLongtitue);

    System.out.println("point length::" +point);
    System.out.println("point length::" +title);
    System.out.println("point length::" +address);

    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, title,address);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
}
```

Comment: is this line System.out.println("value of title:::"+title);
 print different titles or last one only?

Comment: yes it prints all the titles from the api but display's the last one on each click of the pin point

Answer (score 0):

Just rearranged your code now try and please tell::

```
mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();  
Drawable drawable = myrefgps.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);
for(int i = 0;i<adapt_objgps.latitude_array.length;i++){
    double dLat = Double.parseDouble(adapt_objgps.latitude_array[i]) *1E6;
    double dLongotitue =Double.parseDouble(adapt_objgps.longitude_array[i]) *  1E6;
    int iLat = (int) dLat;
    int iLongtitue = (int) dLongotitue;
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(iLat, -iLongtitue);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, adapt_objgps.title_array[i],adapt_objgps.address_array[i]);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
}
```

Comment: sorry but its showing the same again last title is displaying on both pinpoints

Comment: but how paste your solution. might be helpfull for other too.

Comment: List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapview.getOverlays(); 
  Drawable drawable = myrefgps.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);
  HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);
  
  
  for(int i = 0;i<adapt_objgps.latitude_array.length;i++){
      double dLat = Double.parseDouble(adapt_objgps.latitude_array[i]) *1E6;
      double dLongotitue =Double.parseDouble(adapt_objgps.longitude_array[i])

Comment: int iLat = (int) dLat;
      int iLongtitue = (int) dLongotitue;
      
      GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(iLat, -iLongtitue);
      OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, adapt_objgps.title_array[i],adapt_objgps.address_array[i]);
      overlayitem.setMarker(drawable);
      itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
      mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

Comment: whats the difference b/w my answer and yours

Comment: HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);                                                This line should be outside the for loop and inside the loop           overlayitem.setMarker(drawable); should be added then we can do it correctly